# Installing Neovim v0.8.1 with Guix makes some treesitter parser unusuable because of GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found

Tags: version, guix, nvim

It seems that guix compile neovim with gcc 10.3 which does not come with `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` (like described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)). The exact error provided while opening neovim with an html file for example is :

```
Error detected while processing BufNewFile Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...vwccg5g0rcy-neovim-0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:22: Error execu
ting lua: ...vwccg5g0rcy-neovim-0.8.1/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:23: Vim(append):Error executing lua
 callback: Failed to load parser: uv_dlopen: /gnu/store/094bbaq6glba86h1d4cj16xhdi6fk2jl-gcc-10.3.0-lib/l
ib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/chillpc/.local/share/nvim/lazy/n
vim-treesitter/parser/html.so)
stack traceback:

...
```

From the package description, neovim use the cmake build system and pkg-config. I didn't see any possibility to specify the gcc version used in order to get everything needed. Just installing the last version of gcc does not, of course, fix my issue.

Can you give me pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded by installing neovim like this :

```
guix install neovim --with-c-toolchain=neovim=gcc-toolchain@12
```

Reference [in the package transformation documentation](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Package-Transformation-Options.html)

Comment: I have the exact same problem but on Windows. Do you know how to do the same but on Windows?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not use it and therefore can't answer you. Maybe try to compile it yourself with an up to date gcc.